# Why does not Windows statically allocate RAM for Intel Integrated Graphics?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, intel-graphics, memory-management

I wanted to know how much RAM is being utilized.  It said that out of the 12 GB installed, 7 gb was allocated overall and it showed me the split up for each processes.

I could not find the RAM allocated to my Graphics Cards - Intel HD4600.  Why does this happen?

Can I assume that Intel HD4600 does have access to the 2gb (approx) RAM it is supposed (>8gb condition) to have access to?

Comment: For some silly marketing reason, Intel likes to claim that their embedded GPUs can use large amounts of memory. They can, it's true, but nobody would ever actually want to do this under any circumstances. Using that much memory would make performance *awful*. Memory access is the limiting factor in embedded GPU performance and ingenious compression techniques are employed to allow embedded GPUs to make do with as little memory as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statically assigning a large amount of RAM only for the GPU, even if you don't need that amount of GPU memory, would prevent other applications from using it.

You can see the amount of the GPU memory usage in [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) or [ProcessHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) under the **GPU** tab in system information Window. When you open tools which use a lot of graphics data the usage grows.

If you still "miss" RAM, take a look at [RAMMap](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/08/13/introduction-to-the-new-sysinternals-tool-rammap.aspx) which shows you a lot of details how Windows uses the physical RAM.